# How do i run a python doctest in windows?

Tags: python, windows

I learned how to do this on Unix lab computers, and none of the commands are working ? 
I found other stack overflow questions about modifying the path directory and when i type python in Cmd, the python program starts to work. However, I don't know how to open a file i want to test ? 
is the command still -m doctest file_to_be_tested ?

Also, do I have to go to that point in my directory before I can open python ?

Somethings that i have tried are: 
1) opening python first, and then going to where my file is, and then trying the -m doctest command
2) going to the directory place first, and then opening python, then the -m doctest command

I am pretty confused. 
If it makes a difference, I am using sublime as a text editor

Comment: You have to give path to doctest-file.py in `python -m doctest <file>`. In windows you have to escape `\` with extra `\`. So a path like `C:\foo\bla.txt` can be accessed on command prompt or python interpreter as ``C:\\foo\\bla.txt``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Somethings that i have tried are: 1) opening python first, and then going to where my file is, and then trying the -m doctest command 2) going to the directory place first, and then opening python, then the -m doctest command

`-m` is a *command-line switch*, it has no meaning inside the interpreter.

You need to go to the directory that contains the file you want to test and run:

```
> python -m doctest file-to-test
```